# Finder "Arrange by date" splits into Today, Previous 7 Days, Previous 30 Days, etc

Tags: finder, ui, sort

When I use Finder on OSX 10.11.6, selecting any of the "Arrange by date [modified/last opened/created/added]" splits up the window into various vertical subcategories which I can either horizontally scroll through or go through one by one and select "show all" to have them treated like regular files.

Is there anyway to disable this and just have all the files in the folder sorted chronologically in the same way it treats files when you sort by name? I believe the behavior I'm looking for is the same as Windows 10 behavior.

**[EDIT]**

Just to clarify, I am wanting to achieve this in icon view, not in one of the other views.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it only does that in the 'All My Files' folder, which is a special folder type.

Comment: @Tetsujin sadly no, i just checked and it does it in Downloads Desktop and a bunch of folders that I made on my own

Comment: hmm... yup, it does it in anything first set to icon view before choosing that sort. As I never use icon view, I hadn't realised. I mainly use list view & then you can sort by clicking any header & that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Tetsujin unfortunately in list view it does the same thing, even afte clicking a header to sort. http://i.imgur.com/13CzNYL.png

Comment: Yes, but the trick in list view is to remove the View/sort [set to None] & just click the headers instead

Comment: Oh i see. that's cool but i'm really looking for a way to do this with icon view. thanks though!

Comment: Yup - fraid I can't help on that one, sorry. Wish you luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right Click → `Show View Options`. In the small window that opens, set `Arrange By` and `Sort By` to "None". Close the small window.

Right Click Again → `Clean Up By` → `Date Modified` or `Date Created`.

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent option for "Last Opened" or "Added", as far as I'm aware.

Comment: damn this sure isn't intuitive but thanks so much !

Comment: Great question. But not seeing any `Show View Options` when I right click. However, I notice when I right click in empty space I can uncheck `Use Grouping`, which then produces a giant mess. But then I can right click again and choose `Sort by` and then `Date Added`, etc.  :-)