# Prevent "Yesterday", "Previous 7 days" groupings when uploading files on macOS?

Tags: macos, finder, google-chrome

When uploading to chrome (presumably in other browsers/applications too), how can the files be made to appear as a regular list *without* the gaps/sections for "Yesterday", "Previous 7 Days" etc:

[image]

#### What know so far

- I found [how to remove relative date grouping for *Finder*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287700/290197).
- Right clicking does nothing
- There's no `(...)` symbol that shows more options like there is in Finder

Comment: Incredibly irritating "feature". Glad you asked.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the little set of six squares, then for "Group items by", select "None":

[image]